# Rename Title field in list definition SP 2013

Tags: 2013, xslt-list-view-web-part, sharepoint-addin

Similar questions have been asked before but none of the solutions have worked so far for me.

The list I am working with is part of an add-in so no settings menu is available. I am trying to rename the `Title` field within the list definition. I have set the display name for the `Title`, `LinkTitle`, and `LinkTitleNoMenu` fields to "Last Name" however nothing is changed on the list - it still displays `Title`.

```
<Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" DisplayName="Last Name" Required="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" MaxLength="255" />
<Field ID="{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}" Type="Computed" Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="Last Name" StaticName="LinkTitle" />
<Field ID="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" Type="Computed" Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" DisplayName="Last Name" StaticName="LinkTitleNoMenu" />
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be missing in order to rename the title field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to close the browser, clear the cache and then try agaon?

Comment: I just tried that and it unfortunately still displays Title

Comment: May be try use list GUID to access the list setting page as bellow:  http://yoursitename/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List=<List GUID>
If that one doesn't work, you can always use powershell the access that list for configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try:

```
<Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}"  Type="Text" Name="Title" DisplayName="Renamed Title" Required="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" />
  <Field ID="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" Type="Computed" DisplayName="Renamed Title" StaticName="LinkTitle" Name="LinkTitle"   />
  <Field ID="{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}" Type="Computed" DisplayName="Renamed Title" StaticName="LinkTitleNoMenu" Name="LinkTitleNoMenu"  />
```

Please verify the GUID with Internal Name of the field.

`{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}` - `LinkTitleNoMenu`
`{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}` - `LinkTitle`